tflint azure devops agent not found
i have a strange behavior with tflint.
i am getting an error in azure self hosted devops agent.
[INFO] Load config: .tflint.hcl
[INFO] file not found
[INFO] Load config: /home/AzDevOps/snap/tflint/52/.tflint.hcl
[INFO] file not found
[INFO] Use default config
[INFO] The "terraform" plugin block is not found. Enable the plugin "terraform" automatically
Failed to find workspaces; open .: permission denied
[INFO] Load config: .tflint.hcl
[INFO] file not found
[INFO] Load config: /home/AzDevOps/snap/tflint/52/.tflint.hcl
[INFO] file not found
[INFO] Use default config
[INFO] The "terraform" plugin block is not found. Enable the plugin "terraform" automatically

Terraform is in modules.The main.tf is also at the same level where tflint is. the tflint.hcl also same level.
Changing the permissions through the script:
chmod -R 755 $(pwd)
export TFLINT_LOG=debug
tflint --init
tflint --recursive

drwxr-xr-x 5 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096  ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 .terraform
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 3412  .terraform.lock.hcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps  313  .tflint.hcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 1973  README.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps  400  tflint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 1022 config.tf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps  643 data.tf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 2832 main.tf
drwxr-xr-x 6 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096  modules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps   89  outputs.tf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 2222  terraform.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 2384  variables.tf

  It runs on self hosted devops agent

config {
  format = "compact"
  disabled_by_default = false
}

plugin "terraform" {
  enabled = true
  preset  = "recommended"
}

plugin "azurerm" {
  enabled = true
  version = "0.25.0"
  source  = "github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm"
}

rule "terraform_required_providers" {
  enabled = false
}


Can you show us the pipeline or the part of the pipeline where you're running tflint?

Are you running the command on the local machine directly? Try ls command to list all files to confirm .tflint.hcl exist. Or you can specify the path tflint --init --config <path>/.tflint.hcl

Also, it might be helpful to see the contents of tflint.hcl

Added also the tflint content

The error is tflint is unable to find the configuration file .tflint.hcl and is falling back to the default configuration, and terraform is not included. How do you install the tflint? It's recommended to re-install it for a check, try command for installation curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terraform-linters/tflint/master/install_linux.sh | bash, then check again.

tflint is installed,should i add the config at each module?

The file list is not aligned. Is your .tflint.hcl under .terraform ? If so, use tflint --init --config .terraform/.tflint.hcl for a check. Or please make sure .tflint.hcl is in the root directory.

no tflint.hcl is at the same level as .terraform. Ad main.tf with tflint also same level.Then there is the modules dir. Locally when i tflint --init --config ./.tflint.hcl it works.

Glad to know it works. You may consider always specifying the --config flag with the path to your .tflint.hcl file when you run tflint. This will ensure that tflint always knows where to find its configuration. I added it in the answer. Thanks.

You can specify the --config flag with the path to your .tflint.hcl file when you run tflint.  This will ensure that tflint always knows where to find its configuration.
tflint --init --config ./.tflint.hcl
My repo structure as below:

And yaml as below:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: CheckTerraformLinting
    jobs:
    - job: Check_Terraform_Linting
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: "true"

        - script: |
            curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terraform-linters/tflint/master/install_linux.sh | bash
            tflint --init --config ./.tflint.hcl
          displayName: 'Install and init tflint'



again its not working.  Failed to load configurations; :0,0-0: Failed to read module directory; Module directory . does not exist or cannot be read.:
Error: Failed to read module directory
on  line 0:
(source code not available)
Module directory . does not exist or cannot be read.

Do you mean it's intermittent? As per the comment before, it works with -config already. Do you still execute on the same machine? May i know what's the difference between two command(working one before and current failure one)

locally its working, i mean on my laptop on vscode. When i execute through the Az DO pipeline as you saw above with ls -la the directories and deverything its not working.

Thanks for clarification. The error now looks different with original one, the current error looks like it cannot read the module directory. What's the user in pipeline? Try to add whoami in bash task for a check, is it same with AzDevOps on local?

whomai comes AzDevOps. On local its my account working in the repo in vscode

Make sure you have synced the code to DevOps repo. Also please show the main.tf content, how do you define the module?

module "VM" {
source = "./modules/vm"
environment = var.environment
location    = var.location
tags        = local.tags
subscription_id     = local.subscription_id
}

I tried same structure and .tflint.hcl, but it works on my pipeline. May i know which command reported the error? tflint --init... or tflint --recursive ...?

Command:   tflint --init --config ./.tflint.hcl   Failed to load TFLint config; failed to load file: open ./.tflint.hcl: no such file or directory.   tflint --version
TFLint version 0.51.1

@joharger, i shared my repo structure and sample yaml, please have a check.

still the same error.It is installed i can see the version.

So with the DEBUG enabled i saw that it is looking for the tflint.hcl in that directory config.go:190: [INFO] Load config: /home/AzDevOps/snap/tflint/44/.tflint.hcl. It wasnt there.But the code is checkoed out ,i can see that with ls -la.And i copied the tflint in the above directory and then it worked. Should i change something ?

As per the config /home/AzDevOps/snap/tflint/44/.tflint.hcl, you installed tflint via snap while not the bash command(github link), as i mentioned before, please uninstall tflint and restart agent. Copy my task content to install tflint and init.

I am using Vm images i build it with packer.I tried to install with that command but after the image is deployed as ( self hosted devops vm) it couldnt find the tflint path.

Checked with Ubuntu linux self-hosted agent, the script works fine. The issue is caused by tflint is not properly installed on your agent machine. Please try to create a linux azure VM, and set it as agent for a check. If you use VMSS or self image, it's recommended to get local IT support to fix it.
